# Bootstrap: Why don't badges in tab navigations repond to the active state by default?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, badges in pill navigations [respond to the active state](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#adapts-to-active-nav-states), but badges in tab navigations do not.

I got the desired behaviour by adding a CSS class for a badge in an active tab navigation:

```
/* Active bootstrap badges on active tabs */
.nav-tabs .active a .badge {
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a good reason why this is not the default behaviour?

Comment: try like this background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202) !important;

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.nav-tabs .active a .badge {
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
}
```

and must be in file after bootstrap file so will overwrite the default